# Netbeans no reconoce Cygwin

Tags: c, netbeans

He tenido que instalar Netbeans en mi portátil para C según una guía. Así, me instalé el JDK y Cygwin con make, debugger, etc.

Al iniciar netbeans pone que no existe el JDK, le doy a desactivar módulos y continuar y funciona. Puedo escribir el programa, pero a la hora de compilarlo aparece el error de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] (a pesar de haberme funcionado perfectamente en ocasiones anteriores).

Parece que no reconoce Cygwin, lo desinstalo, lo vuelvo a instalar y funciona con normalidad aunque no reconozca el JDK.

Reinicias el ordenador y el error reaparece. Mis profesores no saben qué puede ser (me han recomendado esta web) y necesito Netbeans.

¿Alguna idea para subsanar el error?

Comment: Hola pedrog99. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Qué imagen?  Este problema parece no ser reproducible si dices que tus profesores no saben arreglarlo. Intenta añadir toda la informacion pertinente del error, asi como versiones. Mira tambien [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Ahora que veo la imagen, veo que puedes sustituirla por el texto de la misma. Copialo y ponlo en la pregunta en vez de la imagen y a ver si alguien puede ayudarte con ese problema..Suerte

Comment: Deberias revisar las configuración de netbeans para asegurarte de que las rutas y los parametros son correctos

Comment: ¿Cómo se hace eso? Gracias por responder